# id passing between 2 pages in PHP

Tags: php, variables, get

I've been working on a way to get a variable passed from one page to another. It's for my exam and I need help with it as my teacher said I could use the internet for help. This link that I've created to pass the variable isn't working as the student id or email is suppose to be passed into the link. This is the relative code:

```
echo "<table border=1><th colspan=7>Placed Orders</th></tr><tr><td>Student ID or Email</td><td>Name</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Room Number</td><td>Order</td><td>Approval</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row["StudentIDorEmail"];
    $name = $row["Name"];
    $phone = $row["Phone"];
    $roomnumber = $row["RoomNumber"];
    $order = $row["Orders"];
    $approval = $row["Approved"];
    echo "<tr><td align='center'>" . $id . "</td><td align='center'>" . $name . "</td><td align='center'>" . $phone . "</td><td align='center'>" . $roomnumber . "</td><td align='center'>" . $order . "</td><td align='center'>" . $approval . "</td><td align='center'><a href='approve.php?id=".$id."'>Fill Order</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I'm trying to pass the variable to the approve.php page so that I can make that row get set to 1 and then when it changes to one, it gets deleted from the database. It's been causing me to keep erroring and I don't know what is wrong. Here is the other part of relative code for the page that it's suppose to be passed to and from:

```
$id = $_GET["StudentIDorEmail"];
$query = "UPDATE tracker WHERE StudentIDorEmail=$id";
if (mysql_query($query, $con)) {
$query1 = "DELETE FROM tracker WHERE Approved=1";
if(mysql_query($query1, $con)) {
    echo "Order was filled successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

}

Please help because this is the requirements for my exam and I've almost finished it.

Comment: Why you don't use sessions ? http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @MohammadAhmad Erm, because it's a loop with different links, of which the user selects one?

Comment: Another issue: Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or in this case maybe `intval()` to avoid SQL injections!

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo That alone won't help, since I could just write `1 or 1=1`. There's nothing to escape and that would wipe everything.

Comment: @Kolink I just overread it... In most cases the escape would be enough... I for myself would use `intval` on id-fields... But who knows which data types he's using with variable names like `StudentIDorEmail` which could also be a string.

Comment: FYI, the very first `</tr>` tag in the very first echo should be deleted.  It does not match any opening `<tr>` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your link is `'approve.php?id=".$id."'`

This means you need to access `$_GET['id']`, not `$_GET['StudentIDorEmail']`.

For future reference, try `var_dump($_GET)` to see what variables are there.

EDIT: You should learn about SQL injection.

[image: XKCD]

In this case, you can use `$id = intval($_GET['id'])` to ensure you only get numbers.

Comment: I changed the link to 'approve.php?StudentIDorEmail=".$id."' it works on passing the id but now the logic portion of the approve script doesn't work. I don't understand what's going other than it's coming up as false.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for all your help. It was quite confusing but then again, I never really understood it completely even after looking at several videos and examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy,

```
<a href='approve.php?id=".$id."'>
```

Change this to:

```
<a href='approve.php?StudentIDorEmail=".$id."'>
```